# How do you set jobrunr in run now/eager mode for spring integration testing

Tags: jobrunr

I must be missing something obvious. I've got a couple of jobrunr jobs where i'm using the lambda enqueue format version 5.1.6. Like this:

```
JobId jobId = BackgroundJob.<MyService>enqueue(x -> x.doWork());
```

I would like to validate the plumbing and work in the jobs is executing via some integration tests with Spring, but don't see the options to run now, eager mode, etc?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid.

You can mock the JobScheduler and capture the args. JobRunr itself is also tested very well so if you pass a job, you can rest assured it will be enqueued.

You could also put the pollIntervalInSeconds to  5 and use awaitility then to verify your job executed. There are many examples of this in the JobRunr repo.

Comment: How do you make it run immediately or at least give it a maximum waiting time before running? Because my tasks are taking even up to 2 minutes on the queue without being run. Which is not good when you have tasks that need to be fired immediately in the background